# searching for reusable course ontology

Tags: semantic-web, ontology

I want to develop smart e-learning system which retrieve the suitable learning objects to the learner according to his/her learning style.

now, I need two ontology, the first for the learner model and the second for the learning object.

please, i want reusable ontology about a course like('java.owl', 'c#.owl', or 'any course.owl').

i tries to search a lot but i cannot find what i need.

For example when i writes this words('java.owl', 'c#.owl', or 'any course.owl') on the search engine, i cannot find any effective result about the course ontology.

can any one help me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where to find ontologies specific to programming languages, but there are a few ontologies about learning objects. One example would be the ontologies used at BBC for describing school curricula, available [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/curriculum). I believe the license allows you to reuse them.